# Select data specific id and add value where other data

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello,**

I have a problem that I can not solve..

I have this :

```
<li><div class="bar" data-id="0" data-percentage="0"></div><span>0</span></li>
```

now i want select `data-id = 0 (or 1,2,3,4..) and update data-percentage +10`

How i can do this ?

var data_id = 0;

```
$('[data-id="'+data_id+'"]').text(Number($('div.bar').attr('data-percentage', 10)));
```

Thx for help !

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I try add +10 where data-percentage="0" if data-costap="'+data_id+'"

Comment: I can't see no element with `data-costap` in your post.

Comment: Yep error sry, its data_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with callback where the callback holds the second argument as it's old value.

```
$('[data-id="' + data_id + '"]').attr('data-percentage', function(i, v) {
  // parse the number and if it's NaN then treat it as 0
  return (Number(v) || 0) + 10;
});
```

Comment: This will fail if `isNaN(v)`. I know it answers OP but mentioning for clarity as this will only work if `data-id` string contains numbers.

Comment: @Kilmazing : now it will treat as 0 when it's NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://codepen.io/landaida/pen/VPagXQ),

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  incrementTen(0);
})

function incrementTen(dataId){
  let el = $('[data-id='+dataId+']'), 
  initialValue = $(el).data('percentage');
  $(el).attr('percentage', initialValue+10)
  console.log(initialValue, $(el)[0].outerHTML)
}
```

Comment: what's difference ?

Comment: nothing, when I wrote the solution the above answer was not there